# OpenLDAP monitor access ACL not working

Tags: ldap, centos7, openldap

I'm unable to retrieve the monitor information with OpenLDAP running on CentOS 7. In order to set everything up I've followed the steps documented [here](https://blog.kmp.or.at/monitoring-openldap/):

```
$ cat module_monitor.ldif
dn: cn=module{0},cn=config
changetype: modify
add: olcModuleLoad
olcModuleLoad: {2}back_monitor

$ sudo ldapmodify -Y EXTERNAL -H ldapi:/// -f module_monitor.ldif
```

confirming it worked:

```
 $ sudo ldapsearch -Y EXTERNAL -H ldapi:/// -b "cn=module{0},cn=config"
 SASL/EXTERNAL authentication started
 SASL username: gidNumber=0+uidNumber=0,cn=peercred,cn=external,cn=auth
 SASL SSF: 0
 # extended LDIF
 #
 # LDAPv3
 # base <cn=module{0},cn=config> with scope subtree
 # filter: (objectclass=*)
 # requesting: ALL
 #

 # module{0}, config
 dn: cn=module{0},cn=config
 objectClass: olcModuleList
 cn: module{0}
 olcModulePath: /usr/lib64/openldap
 olcModuleLoad: {0}memberof
 olcModuleLoad: {1}refint
 olcModuleLoad: {2}back_monitor
 <...>
```

Next adding *monitor* account:

```
$ cat cn_monitor.ldif 
dn: cn=monitor,dc=company,dc=de
objectClass: simpleSecurityObject
objectClass: organizationalRole
cn: monitor
description: LDAP monitor
userPassword: {CRYPT}REDACTED

$ ldapadd -x -D "cn=admin,dc=company,dc=de" -W -f cn_monitor.ldif -ZZ -H ldap://openldap.internal.company.de
```

And finally configuring the ACL:

```
$ cat database_monitor.ldif
dn: olcDatabase={1}monitor,cn=config
changetype: modify
replace: olcAccess
olcAccess: {0}to * by dn.base="gidNumber=0+uidNumber=0,cn=peercred,cn=external,cn=auth" read by dn.base="cn=manager,dc=company,dc=de" read by * none

$ sudo ldapmodify -Y EXTERNAL -H ldapi:/// -f database_monitor.ldif
```

confirming it worked:

```
$ sudo ldapsearch -Y EXTERNAL -H ldapi:/// -b "olcDatabase={1}monitor,cn=config"

SASL/EXTERNAL authentication started
SASL username: gidNumber=0+uidNumber=0,cn=peercred,cn=external,cn=auth
SASL SSF: 0
# extended LDIF
#
# LDAPv3
# base <olcDatabase={1}monitor,cn=config> with scope subtree
# filter: (objectclass=*)
# requesting: ALL
#

# {1}monitor, config
dn: olcDatabase={1}monitor,cn=config
objectClass: olcDatabaseConfig
olcDatabase: {1}monitor
olcAccess: {0}to * by dn.base="gidNumber=0+uidNumber=0,cn=peercred,cn=external
 ,cn=auth" read by dn.base="cn=manager,dc=company,dc=de" read by * none
```

Now I can retrieve the monitor information using EXTERNAL authentication with sudo:

```
$ sudo ldapsearch -Y EXTERNAL -H ldapi:/// -b "cn=monitor"
<...>
# numResponses: 67
# numEntries: 66
```

Unfortunately I can't achieve the same with the *monitor* user:

```
$ ldapsearch -D "cn=monitor,dc=company,dc=de" -H ldap://openldap.internal.company.de -W -ZZ  -b "cn=monitor"
Enter LDAP Password:
# extended LDIF
#
# LDAPv3
# base <cn=monitor> with scope subtree
# filter: (objectclass=*)
# requesting: ALL
#

# search result
search: 3
result: 32 No such object

# numResponses: 1
```

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your access list does not include `cn=monitor,dc=company,dc=de`. As such the dn you are trying to use is getting caught by the `by * none` part of your olcAccess rule. (Without this section the same thing would have happened implicitly rather than explicitly.)

The following ldif should work as desired:

```
dn: olcDatabase={1}monitor,cn=config
changetype: modify
replace: olcAccess
olcAccess: {0}to *
  by dn.base="gidNumber=0+uidNumber=0,cn=peercred,cn=external,cn=auth" read
  by dn.base="cn=manager,dc=company,dc=de" read
  by dn.base="cn=monitor,dc=company,dc=de" read
  by * none
```